# set cornerRadius of class using UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uiappearance

So far I have changed image of all the buttons which are in my class by using the following code

```
   [[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[FirstPadViewController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

As I dont want to create an outlet that is why I used this way. So how can I set cornerRadius using UIButton `appearanceWhenContainedIn`

I tried this but it does not work

```
 [[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[FirstPadViewController class], nil] layer ] setCornerRadius:20];
 [[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[FirstPadViewController class], nil] layer ] setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can't do that. And, even if it works, it can break at any moment with any update, or have undefined behavior.

UIAppearance proxy is reserved to method / properties that declares `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`.

Have a look at [this list](https://gist.github.com/mattt/5135521) to see what you can customize with `UIAppearance`. According to it you can change only the `tintColor`. The list is not complete but `layer` (and by extension, `cornerRadius`) is not in the appearance selectors.

Comment: i tried above code but its not working are you sure its not possible cuse man this can really save my lot lot of time

Comment: Well, if I understood the question right, and you want to apply `setCornerRadius` on all `UIButton`, using `UIAppearance`, I don't think it is possible. I might be wrong, but hadn't seen this anywhere.

Comment: yes i think you are right cuse i tried it and nothing is happening

Comment: Sorry about that. Please mark as answer if it is the right answer for the question. Anyway, you might want to try @Sunny's answer, it might for work your case, but I wouldn't recommend it in general cases.

Answer (score -2):

write this code in your class,it'l work but i don't know is it ok for you

```
for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
            UIButton *btn= (UIButton *)view;
            btn.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
            btn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
            btn.layer.borderWidth =5;

        }
```